# Go Tuples alternative

Tags: python, go

I am working my way through MIT Introduction to Computational Thinking and Data Science course lecture 2 [The lecture PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0002-introduction-to-computational-thinking-and-data-science-fall-2016/lecture-slides-and-files/MIT6_0002F16_lec2.pdf) and I am trying to translate the following tree search algorithm python code to Golang. The main problem is the python code is using a tuple.

```
def maxVal(toConsider, avail):
    """Assumes toConsider a list of items, avail a weight
       Returns a tuple of the total value of a solution to the
         0/1 knapsack problem and the items of that solution"""
    if toConsider == [] or avail == 0:
        result = (0, ())
    elif toConsider[0].getCost() > avail:
        #Explore right branch only
        result = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
    else:
        nextItem = toConsider[0]
        #Explore left branch
        withVal, withToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:],
                                     avail - nextItem.getCost())
        withVal += nextItem.getValue()
        #Explore right branch
        withoutVal, withoutToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
        #Choose better branch
        if withVal > withoutVal:
            result = (withVal, withToTake + (nextItem,))
        else:
            result = (withoutVal, withoutToTake)
    
    return result

def testMaxVal(foods, maxUnits, printItems = True):
    print('Use search tree to allocate', maxUnits,
          'calories')
    val, taken = maxVal(foods, maxUnits)
    print('Total value of items taken =', val)
    if printItems:
        for item in taken:
            print('   ', item)
```

I know Go doesnt have tuples and I searched around for a work around.  I tried this solution with no luck:

```
type Food struct {
    name     string
    value    int
    calories int
}

type Pair struct{ //found this work around on another stack overflow question but I think I incorrectly implemented it 
    a,b interface{}
}



func maxVal(toConsider []Food, avail int) Pair{ 
    /*
    Assumes toConsider a list of items, avail a weight
    Returns a tuple of the total value of a solution to the
    0/1 knapsack problem and the items of that solution
    */

    var result Pair //the culprit

    if (toConsider == nil || avail == 0){ //Slices can only be compared to nil so I am not sure this is achieving what I want it to achieve (i.e. checking for an empty list)

        result = Pair{0, nil}
    } else if toConsider[0].calories > avail{
        //explore right branch only
        result = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
    } else{
        nextItem := toConsider[0]
        //explore left branch
        withVal, withToTake := maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail - nextItem.calories)
        withVal = withVal + nextItem.value
        //explore right branch
        withoutVal, withoutToTake := maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)
        //choose better branch
        if withVal > withoutVal{
            result = Pair{withVal, withToTake + (nextItem)}
        }
    }
    return result
}

func testMaxVal(foods []Food, maxUnits int, printItems bool) {
    printItems = true
    fmt.Printf("Use search tree to allocate %d calories", maxUnits)
    val, taken := maxVal(foods, maxUnits)
    fmt.Printf("\nTotal value of items taken = %d", val)
    if printItems{
        for i := range taken{
            fmt.Print("\n ", i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is often the problem with translating code. Rather than trying to translate a python tuple into Go, look at your base requirements and implement them in Go, using Go concepts.

Comment: Well I am new to Go and am trying to learn it by going through this course and filing the gaps by implementing the code in Go while learning the concepts. I try to find the solutions on my own but when stuck I come here, but you are very correct. I should have been trying to do this instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go does not have tuples, but it can return multiple values:

```
func maxval(toConsider []Food, avail int) (int,[]Food) {
   if len(toConsider)==0 || avail == 0) { // len(toConsider)==0 will work even if toConsider is nil
      return 0,nil
   }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you!